# Height won't work on 'A' tag

Tags: html, css

I am making a navigation bar and I want all of the links in it to be 30px high. When I set this - `height:20px;` (20 pixels because there is 5px padding all around) - the height just stays normal. My full code for the a's is:

```
#header a {
    height:20px;
    background-color:#666666;
    color:white;
    text-decoration:none;
    border:none;
    padding:5px;
}

#header a:hover {
    background-color:#CCCCCC;
    color:black;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lcupj/

Comment: `<a>` is an inline element, and `height` property is not applicable to inline elements. You have to change the default display type of the anchor to `block`/`inline-block` as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `height` property does not apply to elements that are `display: inline` and `<a>` elements are `display: inline` by default.

Set a different value for the `display` property (such as `inline-block`) or use `line-height` instead.

Comment: That centered the text but didn't make it change height.

Comment: You're only adjusting the height by a couple of pixels, it's not very noticeable (if you are talking about making it fill the container, then you have to account for vertical position and the padding on the header element)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a padding on A tag, and use line-height either.
example :

```
a {
    padding : 9px;
    line-height : 20px;
}
```

Bye.

Comment: I modified your code to make your "a" tag more like you want i guess.
http://jsfiddle.net/Lcupj/1/

Comment: I have used this and changed it around a little to get it to fit Just Right! `[`http://jsfiddle.net/Lcupj/2/`]`

Answer (score 0):

`height` won't apply to inline blocks.

Use `display: inline-block` in your CSS to make the element behave like an inline element but with some of the block element properties.

Answer (score 0):

Add to the a rule `display:inline-block` in CSS

Comment: `Display Block` made the link go below the text and fill the whole width

Comment: You're right @zoweb, I meant inline-block. Updated my answer. Rahil Wazir, I'm not sure where you mean critique, I said to add to the rule.

Answer (score 0):

you can also try the following

```
#header a {
    position:absolute;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:20px;
    background-color:#666666;
    color:white;
    text-decoration:none;
    border:none;
    padding:5px;
}
```

sometimes you have to manually set the height or padding of a given element, or the element would be squashed to fit inside the other other element. I also use position:absolute this gives 100% control over your elements position, size etc.

http://jsfiddle.net/Lcupj/

Answer (score 0):

use   `display: inline-block;`

```
#header a {
    height:30px;
    background-color:#666666;
    color:white;
    text-decoration:none;
    border:none;
    padding:5px;

    display: inline-block;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Y49xk/)

Answer (score 0):

A is an inline element, you can't use height on it. If you want to do so you must first change it into a block element. You can do so with `display: block;` however this will put your element on a new "line" on your screen, if you want it to stay like an inline element, you should use display: `inline-block;` Or you could use line-height.